# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.Bitmap android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.getBitmap()'

Tags: android, fragment

I have an issue on my project that I want to create an PDF file. When I run my app, before clicking SUBMIT button to create an file PDF from user input, my app works well. However, after clicking SUBMIT button, it exits and I check problem showing:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.Bitmap android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.getBitmap()' on a null object reference

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Pacf.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.